# Could not figure out the use of prefetch_related in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, query-optimization, django-orm

There is a scenario where i want to show total purchase of the user. I did using @property inside models of userprofiles. Fortunately, it is working as i expected. But i want to use prefetch_related for optimizing django queries as total purchase of user is calculated from order_history which has ManyToMany Relation with the OrderMenu.

**How i did ?**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
    restaurant = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant, blank=True)
    order_history = models.ManyToManyField(OrderMenu, blank=True)
    # favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def total_purchase(self):
        total_purchase = 0
        # user_order = UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related('order_history').get(slug=self.slug)
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=self.slug)
        user_order = userprofile.order_history.all()
        for usr in user_order:
            total_purchase += usr.get_cost()
        return total_purchase
```

> In this solution, isn't
>
> userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=self.slug) user_order =
>   userprofile.order_history.all()
>
> is equivalent to
>
> user_order=UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related('order_history').get(slug=self.slug)

I am so much confused with prefetch_related. Could anyone please enlighten me with simple language? Sorry i am non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two is

In case of

`userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=self.slug)` #hits database

This query gets the object of userprofile based on condition from database

`user_order = userprofile.order_history.all()` #hits database again

This query gets user_order queryset using userprofile object hitting database again.

i.e. userprofile hits database as well as user_order

In this case however

`user_order=UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related('order_history').get(slug=self.slug)`

user_order queryset set returns not only user profile object but also 'order_history' queryset that is related to UserProfile object in one hit to database. Now when you access 'order_history' querset with user_order object it will not hit database, but gets the queryset of 'order_history' from prefetched QuerySet cache of 'user_order'. more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets).

Comment: That's what i understand about prefetch_related so i did  user_order=UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related('order_history').get(slug=self.slug) and iterate over user_order to calculate the total cost using total + usr.get_cost() but i get an error of 'UserProfile' object is not iterable

Comment: I have added model part too. Why do i get an error of 'UserProfile' object is not iterable when i iterate over user_order which use prefetch_related to fetch the function of get_cost of OrderMenu?

Comment: user_order is a single object of UserProfile, it is not a queryset, you cannot iterate using user_order. if you want to iterate do not use get, user filter to get queryset instead of object. something like user_order=UserProfile.objects.prefetch_related('order_history').filter(slug=self.slug) which returns queryset(list of objects of UserProfile based on the match) .

Comment: then i cannot access an attribute and function of OrderMenu because its an object of UserProfile only.

Comment: I don't know what OrderMenu is but if it is 'OrderHistory'(a model related to UserProfile) you can access attribute and function by using the object. the only difference his when you use get you get an object not list which is not an iterable. you can access with object, but you cannot use for loop, that was my point. hope this help you, if it did, accept my answer thanks.

Comment: OrderMenu has attribute of price, quantity and get_cost(). I wanted to access that. Anyhow i got to learn from you. Definitely i am accepting your answer.